# Camel-Spring Boot: Route doesn't stop after execution

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-sql

I am using Spring Boot + Camel with below config.

**Main Class**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends RouteBuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("sql:{{list.sql}}?dataSource=#dataSource")
        .log("process row ${body}")
        .to("stream:out");
    }}
```

**application.properties**

```
camel.springboot.name=ListJob
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true

list.sql=<SELECT QUERY>

spring.datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=un
spring.datasource.password=pwd
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>wl-event-notification-batch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>notification</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Spring Boot runs the route in infinite loop executing SELECT query because of **"camel.springboot.main-run-controller"** property until I hit CNTRL+C. If I remove this property, application just starts and stops the route immediately without completing the execution.

Can someone please help me, to get my route start, execute the steps and stop when I run Spring Boot application?

Comment: You want to select from the database only ONCE and then process that and stop?

Comment: Yes, I want my route to run once execute my select, query process and stop.

Comment: Use a timer and tell it to run once, and then you can stop a route from a route: http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

Comment: Unfortunately the link does not help, because instead of the code there is only an error message: `Error formatting macro: snippet: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 20`. So I'm not able to see what should be done :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spring-boot properties:

```
# handle only one 1 message and then stop the route
camel.springboot.duration-max-messages=1
# run for 180 seconds and then gracefully shutdown
camel.springboot.duration-max-seconds=180
# a polling consumer will cancel the graceful shutdown so set the shutdownTimeout to a minimum
camel.springboot.shutdownTimeout=1
```

Answer (score -2):

add **.stop()**:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("sql:{{list.sql}}?dataSource=#dataSource")
        .log("process row ${body}")
        .stop();
    }
```

Comment: This does not help at all, as `.stop()` only marks the current exchange as completet and stops further routing